Typescript throws error when using a interface for a function having constructor signature and normal signature (function overload)
I am trying to define a function which as two call signatures.
Interface for the function
type CallOrConstruct = {
  (n: number): string;
  new (s: string): Date; // Add constructor signature
};


Function implementation
function fn(input: number | string): string | Date {
  if (typeof input === "number") {
    return input.toString();
  }
  return new Date(input);
}


Calling the function
function callableFn(
  fn: CallOrConstruct,
  input: number | string
): string | Date {
  if (typeof input === "number") {
    return fn(input);
  }
  return new (fn as CallOrConstruct)(input);
}

callableFn(fn, 124); 
callableFn(fn, "2024-04-06");

Typescript is throwing below errors:
Error 1:
error TS2345: Argument of type '(input: string | number) => string | Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CallOrConstruct'.
Type 'string | Date' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'.
callableFn(fn, 124);
Error 2:
error TS2345: Argument of type '(input: string | number) => string | Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CallOrConstruct'.
callableFn(fn, "2024-04-06")
I have gone through the documentation but I am not able to solve this.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
I have tried to use type assertion to match the type signature. Implemented narrowing to match the overloading signature of the function but it is also not helping.
I am expecting to execute a function which as a overloading behavior with one of the overloading implementation having a constructor signature as a return value.

fn isn't a class constructor, so it's not a CallOrConstruct. If you want fn to be treated as one, you'll need fn as CallOrConstruct. The type assertion inside callableFn wouldn't have any effect (the fact that you call that parameter fn is confusing, since now it's not clear what you mean when you say fn. Maybe give those different names)?  You could write this if you want your type assertion to last the whole lifetime of fn, but I'm not sure why you think that function is a good candidate to be a constructor function; why would you call new fn("")?

@jcalz thank you for the reply. I am new to typescript and was trying to replicate a function implementation which can be called as a regular function and also as a constructor just like a Date object. From Typescript documentation - "Some objects, like JavaScript’s Date object, can be called with or without new". Hence new fn(""). An function or a Class is at the end a object in JS was my thought :).

also, why does "const fn = fn1 as CallOrConstruct" works? I tried to define "function fn:CallOrConstruct (){}" but it throws same error. If you can share some insight that would be great. Thanks a lot.

But your fn() is not acting like a constructor. You don't need new fn(""), fn("") will work just fine. Generally speaking constructors start doing stuff with this, or put things on a prototype object. Are you new to JS as well as TS? Your fn function doesn't look anything like a constructor. Just because the implementation of fn calls a constructor with new doesn't mean fn itself should be called with new.  Those are essentially unrelated. Please [edit] to clarify and hopefully provide a [mre] that actually demonstrates a case where you'd want a combo fn/ctor.
